# 2 php versions installed(5.6&7) how to add pecl ssh2 ext only to the 5.6 installation?

Tags: linux, pecl, ispconfig

I've installed 2 php versions on my server (which is managed by ISPconfig 3) using this howto:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I'm trying to add pecl ssh2 extension only to my 5.6 installation.

```
cd /opt/php-5.6.30/etc
pecl -C pear.conf install ssh2-0.13

pecl/ssh2 requires PHP (version >= 4.0.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Also tried to change shell php alias to:
 
    alias php=/opt/php-5.6.30/bin/php - IT DIDN'T WORK :(

Comment: Please help.. I'm desperate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by changing the pecl script to always work through php5.6 version

Edited:

```
nano /usr/bin/pecl
```

And added this line after the first code block (after it checks the php version )

```
PHP="/opt/php-5.6.30/bin/php"
```

Don't forget to change it back after installation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
pecl install ssh2-1.1.2
```

You can see available versions [HERE](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)

For those using alpine linux, make sure to add libssh2-dev first:

```
apk --update add libssh2-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install beta version.

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y git libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev && \
pecl install ssh2-beta
```